# From which episode of TOS was this gif of Spock pulling clothes out of a dresser drawer taken?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

[image: TOS Spock pulling clothes from dresser]

Which episode of *TOS* was this gif of Spock pulling clothes out of a dresser drawer taken from? I saw it on a Facebook comment and it's driving me crazy that I don't remember ever seeing this scene.

Comment: Can you find a link to an actual GIF? It's not necessary to display it directly but some will definitely enjoy viewing it. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 22):

The episode in question is *Star Trek: The Original Series* S01E12, **"[The Conscience of the King](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Conscience_of_the_King_(episode))"**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Conscience_of_the_King):

> "The Conscience of the King" is the 13th episode of the first season of the American science-fiction television series *Star Trek*. Written by Barry Trivers and directed by Gerd Oswald, it was first aired on December 8, 1966.
>
> The episode takes its title from the concluding lines of Act II of Hamlet: "The play's the thing/Wherein I'll catch the conscience of the king."
>
> **In the episode, Captain Kirk crosses paths with an actor suspected of having been a mass-murdering dictator 20 years earlier.**

From the [Star Trek Prop, Costume & Auction Authority](http://www.startrekpropauthority.com/2009/10/captain-kirks-quarters-on-original.html):

> In the 1st season episode "The Conscience of the King" (first airdate: Dec. 8, 1966), some wide angle views capture the overall layout of the room that features a distinct sleeping area, an office area and a dresser/grooming area. **The Quarters are being searched by Kirk and Spock who are trying to locate a phaser on overload that has been hidden in the room**
>
> [image]

Comment: LogicDictates, Thank you SO MUCH. Now, I can sleep. :-D

Comment: @Donna - If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].